# php email not reading html

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

For some reason, the html fails to render in gmail, but renders in hotmail.

Its vital that gmail reads the html, so I wonder which changes I should make to this header.

```
    $from = "info@email.co";
    $headers = "From: bob at info.co <" .($from) . ">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".($from) . "\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: ".($from) . "\n";;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\n";
```

The message starts of as:

```
 $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= "<p>";

    $message .= "Hi $clean_fullName, <br><br>";
    $message .= " Well, I've looked at what you shared with me and I'm delighted to include my personal learning suggestions that I hope will help you achieve your startup goals.";
    $message .= "<br><br>";
    $message .= "If they aren't quite what you're looking for, I take criticism better than most Entrepreneur Wizards
    so please let me know by responding to this email and I'll take another look for you.";
    $message .= "<br><br>";
    $message .= "


    $message .="<br><br>Otherwise, happy learning!<br><br>";

    $message .= "<b>Total Learning time: </b>";
    // create an array of all the duration
    $counter = array();

    foreach($data as $item) {
      // add each duration item to the array after every iteration
      array_push($counter, "{$item['duration']}");
    }

    //record and display the result to the user
    $message .= array_sum($counter);

    $message .= "&nbsp;hours <br><br>";

    foreach($data as $item) {
      $message .= "<b>
      &#10139<a style='color:#FF6400; text-decoration: none' href='{$item['link']}'>{$item['title']}</a></b><br>";
      $message .= "Format: {$item['format']} <br>";
      $message .= "Cost: &#36;{$item['costs']} <br>";
      $message .= "Estimated Duration: {$item['duration']} hours<br>";
      $message .= "<br>";

    }

    $message .= " If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us.  <br><br>";
    $message .= "</p>";

    $message .= '</body></html>';
```

mail

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: well in the message it starts with '<html><body'>' and ends with '</body></html>

Comment: but the html works fine in hotmail but not gmail

Comment: whatever is in those `....` is what we need to see.

Comment: no docutype, no head, valid html has a lot greater chance of working

Comment: not to mention what your `mail()` function looks like, or if it even contains that parameter for the headers.

Comment: look at syntax highlighting here...... as per your edit. syntax errors. right here `$message .= "` that's where error reporting comes in.

Comment: added more detailed in the post

Comment: [3 mins ago, Fred said **this...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341034/php-email-not-reading-html#comment52556896_32341034)

Comment: can elaborate more on error reporting and i dont get whats wrong the line. it doesn't return an error

Comment: Look `$message .= "` that is a syntax error. Either remove it or change it to `$message .= "";` missing a quote and a semi-colon. About error reporting, here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ok.... so.... where are we with this?

Comment: hi i cleaned up the message on thing i find interesting is that in gmail the bold, and the color works fine, just not the <br> or unicode

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning :)

but this should work

```
$from = "info@email.co";
$headers .= 'From: bob at info.co <$from>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: <$from> ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: <$from>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0 ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Priority: 3' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion()' . "\r\n";
```

Answer from comments

```
 $message = '<html><body>';
```

u should do like this

```
$message .= '<html>'. "\r\n";
$message .= '<body>' . "\r\n";
```

You have too much errors in writing missing dot semi etc

as i see your html tag wasn't open at all.

there is lot options to write this template

1.

```
    <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

2.

```
$message.= 'blasldl asdas d asdas' . "\r\n";
$message.= ' sdfadasdasd dsad' . "\r\n";
```

U can change `"\r\n"`with `$rn = "\r\n";` and use it fast as `$rn`

```
$message.= 'blasldl asdas d asdas' . $rn;
$message.= ' sdfadasdasd dsad' . $rn;
```

u can try those solutions and tell me whats happening .
and dont place all email under`<p></p>`

Comment: and y on line 4 u have 2 semicolons

Comment: @Dagon sorry learned.  Never again. Its bad habit from games.

Comment: hey thanks for the response.  
i've used it, but the problem i am noticing is that on gmail the bold and color works fine, just not the <br> or unicode in other words, css seems to work fine, but a bit lost

Comment: Oks i will take look in next half h just to  get home ;)

Comment: Sorry traffic jam  i update answer if you need more let me know